# Passing querystrings to RedirectToRouteResult (beside controller and action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoroute

I have the following code:

```
var routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary {{"action", "Login"}, {"controller", "Persons"}};
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeDictionary);
```

That will produce "`/Persons/Login`"

How can I pass an aditional querystring to the previous code? so that it produces "`/Persons/Login/?someQuerystring=someValue`"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
    new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "action", "login" },
        { "controller", "persons" },
        { "someQuerystring", "someValue" }
    }
);
```