# ASP MVC RedirectToRouteResult with all get query parameters from request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to make redirect in my ActionFilter , with all get parameters that present in request. How I can do it that should I add to my code ?

```
 var routeData = filterContext.RouteData;
     filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                 new RouteValueDictionary(
                                     new
                                    {
                                         culture = code,
                                         controller = routeData.Values["controller"],
                                         action = routeData.Values["action"],
                                         id = routeData.Values["id"],

                                     })
                                );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150647/passing-querystrings-to-redirecttorouteresult-beside-controller-and-action

Comment: When you say "with all get parameters" do you mean query string?

Comment: @StevenV yes query string

Answer (score 9):

You can pull the request query string parameters straight from the `HttpContext` inside the `filterContext`. Then, if there is a value in the route collection that doesn't fit into the matched route, it's added to the query string when the URL is generated.

Knowing all of that, you can enumerate on the query string collection and add them to your RouteValueDictionary. From your example code, the resulting code might look like:

```
var routeData = filterContext.RouteData;

var routeValueDictionary =
    new RouteValueDictionary(
        new
        {
            culture = code,
            controller = routeData.Values["controller"],
            action = routeData.Values["action"],
            id = routeData.Values["id"],
        });

var queryString = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

foreach (var key in queryString.AllKeys)
{
    routeValueDictionary.Add(key, queryString[key]);
}

filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValueDictionary);
```

Comment: This approach has some vulnerabilities. What if someone put "controller" or "action" key in queryString?